# Как передвинуть текст в рамке выше?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как переместить текст в рамке выше?
Дело в том, что этому мешает border, который я не знаю, как обойти. Спасибо, код прилагается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
}


/*Начало SECTION*/

section {
  background: url(/img/fon.png);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
  /*РАМКА*/
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-top: 0px solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
  /*Конец РАМКИ*/
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 109.9vh;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  width: 100%;
  height: 106.9vh;
}

.photo-price {
  height: 100vh;
}

.text-price {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 94vh;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
  border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
  border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}

.text-price {
  font-size: 2.1vh;
  font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}

.text-price p {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.photo-price {
  height: 97vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.border-price {
  max-width: 100px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 4.7vh;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 5px;
  ;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  text-align: center;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 2.1vh;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-sty font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
        <div class="photo-price">
          <div class="text-price">
            <p>Облачения:</p>
            <p>-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> &nbsp; рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
            <p>-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span>&nbsp;</strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
            <p>Подрясники:</p>
            <p>Подризники:</p>
            <p>Рясы:</p>
            <p>Стихари:</p>
            <p>Скуфии:от 800 рублей</p>
            <p>Камилавки:от 1700</p>
            <p>Крещальные:</p>
            <p>Облачения для храма:</p>
            <p>Вышитые кресты:</p>
            <p>Кадильный уголь:</p>
            <p>*парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: не забывайте коды спецсимволов (например, ` & n b s p ; ` ) заканчивать ` ; ` (точка с запятой).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - задать первому абзацу отрицательный margin-top:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}
#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#content-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
}
/*Начало SECTION*/
section {
  background: url(/img/fon.png);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
  /*РАМКА*/
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-top: 0px solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
  /*Конец РАМКИ*/
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 109.9vh;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  width: 100%;
  height: 106.9vh;
}
.photo-price {
  height: 100vh;
}

.text-price {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 94vh;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
  border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
  border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}
.text-price {
  font-size: 2.1vh;
  font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}

.text-price p {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.photo-price {
  height: 97vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.border-price {
  max-width: 100px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 4.7vh;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 5px;;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  
}
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 2.1vh;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
     
     <section>
      <div class="container2">
       <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
           <div class="photo-price">
            <div class="text-price">
               <p style="margin-top: -20px">Облачения:</p>
                  <p>-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> &nbsp; рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
                  <p>-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span>&nbsp;</strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
                  <p>Подрясники:</p>
                  <p>Подризники:</p>
                  <p>Рясы:</p>
                  <p>Стихари:</p>
                  <p>Скуфии:от 800 рублей;</p>
                  <p>Камилавки:от 1700</p>
                  <p>Крещальные:</p>
                  <p>Облачения для храма:</p>
                  <p>Вышитые кресты:</p>
                  <p>Кадильный уголь:</p>
                              <p>*парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу</p>
                           </div>
          </div>
     </div>
          </div>
     </section>
    </main>
```